How do I set memory swappiness for job containers when using the Docker executor for a Gitlab runner?
I have an AWS VM running a Docker executor Gitlab runner. The VM's OS is Amazon Linux 2023. I am having issues with some of my Gitlab jobs running out of memory and want to configure memory swapping to mitigate this. I have memory swappiness setup in my config.toml file, but I when I run a docker inspect command on the job container, I see the memory swappiness is set to null. Why are my job containers not using memory swappiness?
config.toml:
[[runners]]
  name = "aws-runner-1"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  id = <id>
  token = "<runner-token>"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-09-12T13:24:37Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:3.20"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    memory = "1792m"
    memory_swap = "4096m"
    memory_swappiness = 60
    memory_reservation = "256m"
    cpus = "0.9"
    cpuset_cpus = "1"
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0

